# opencCV Calculation of distortion co-efficients(Uncalibrated) to Undistort

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, camera-calibration, distortion

I'm new to openCV using version 2.4.9

I am trying to generate a 3D projection of points from a sequence of images without any knowledge of the camera parameters nor have camera used with me to calibrate. The camera used had a fish eye lens.

I used goodFeaturesToTrack() for detecting feature points followed by LK implementation in openCV to track the feature points in the sequence of images. Using these points I was successfully able to estimate the Fundamental Matrix from findFundamentalMat() and implemented stereoRectifyUncalibrated() to generate rectification homography matrices H1 and H2.Then I have computed Rotation matrix R from H as
R = cameraMatrix^{-1}*H*cameraMatrix

Now I need to undistort my images after rectification. Either by initUndistortRectifyMap() and remap() or directly by undistort(), but both the functions also require "distortion co-efficients" to compute corrected image.
I tried to find various methods to estimate those parameters, neither the documentation of the camera model is made available by the company, nor I could find any other method apart from calibrating camera using chessboards or circles grid.

How do I do it??
Am I doing it right? 
Is there any other better method?
Can someone kindly help?
Thanks in Advance.

//Code

```
        //Fundamental Matrix
                 Mat fundamental_matrix = findFundamentalMat(points[0], points[1], FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99);
                 cout<<"F:\n" <<fundamental_matrix<<endl;
         //Rectification Homographies
         Mat H1, H2,F;
         F = fundamental_matrix;
          stereoRectifyUncalibrated(points[0],points[1], F, image.size(), H1, H2, 3);
          cout<<"H1:\n" <<H1<<endl;
          cout<<"H2:\n" <<H2<<endl;
      //calculating Rotation matrix from homographic maps
            Mat fInv= fundamental_matrix.inv();
            R = (fInv)*H1*fundamental_matrix;


           // Mat distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);
           initUndistortRectifyMap(fundamental_matrix, distCoeffs, R, fundamental_matrix, image.size() ,CV_32FC1,  map1,  map2);
```

//How to compute distCoeffs without a camera nor prior knowledge.Thank You

Comment: imho, impossible. you can make an educated guess about the camera matrix, but not about the distortion coeffs.

Comment: techniques exist to compute only distortion correction without camera intrinsics, but maybe you need a chessboard pattern. afair one paper was called "straight lines have to be straigt". Maybe the method I've seen in action was "A Generic Camera Model and Calibration Method for Conventional, Wide-Angle, and Fish-Eye Lenses" by Kannala & Brandt, but I'm not sure there.

Comment: I don't think you can estimate a _correct_ fundamental matrix if you do not _first_ perform undistortion of the images... Also, you seem to say that you estimate the rotation matrix from the estimated fundamental matrix thanks to the camera matrix. So you do know the intrinsics of the camera? Or Are they just a guess?

Comment: maybe have a look at "Fundamental Matrix for Cameras with Radial Distortion" by Barreto & Daniilidis http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~kostas/mypub.dir/barreto05iccv.pdf

cite: "It is for such cases that our algorithm shows its potential because it relies only on correspondences without any further prior knowledge on the camera or the scene"